# How to properly to create constructor in inner class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have such code:

```
class TopLevelClass {
    private String outstr= "outer";
    public String str = "str toplevel";

    class Inner01 extends TopLevelClass {
        private String strInn01 = "strInn01";
        private String str = "strInner01";

        String getOutStr() {
            return outstr;
        }

        void printStr() {
            System.out.println("Inner01>" + str);
            System.out.println("Inner01>" + Inner01.super.str);
        }

        class Inner02 extends Inner01 {
            public Inner02() {
                this(new TopLevelClass().new Inner01()); // here is compile error
            } 

            public Inner02(TopLevelClass.Inner01 o) {
                o.super();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

There is compile error *"Cannot reference 'Inner01' before supertype constructor has been called"*.

Could You explain why? And what is the correct way of creating a constructor in `Inner02` class with such architecture?

Comment: "here is compile error" what error are you getting?

Comment: Tried on [TIO](https://tio.run/##jZFPT4RADMXv@ykaTkyMrHolet@D8eDReBjZZndWmCGdghrCZ8fOH1wTNZEDU@iv75XHSY/60vVoT/vXZWla7T3ca2Nh2oBcPZlRM8Ijk7EHcAN7plsopEAq6sQML61pVkT6IEA42PUtjtgKl4R31iJdXQO@M9p9MvrVR6aFFTIpxXp1@0GeoSAuWORy/4D8MLA8lGoi5IFs/gio5wSOzuyDqs1UfBkVPjxjVwlexXZryyKb3BVwEaxV/W8615UfeqTqPDvH@/d8br7yyTPnlXLUmZNl@Wh8afEtRlmqKpR5qlSqnmG7hSMSgvHQuK43LQISOfpLMuhU639yanJp4VK08rqbeZNnPGuWIwbYBf@U@dMzaDp4BVOAl@UT), it seems to compile OK

Comment: Cannot reference 'Inner01' before supertype constructor has been called

Comment: How are you trying to compile it? Which tools/versions are you using?

Comment: First of all, this code structure really smells, but any, what is the sense of having a non-argument constructor for `Inner02`? You can't call it before instantiating `Inner01`, thus the constructor `Inner02(TopLevelClass.Inner01 o)` is all you need. (doesn't compile using 1.8.0_141).

Comment: Compiles for me too, javac 1.8.0_92

Comment: @Tom you CAN have a no-args constructor for `Inner02` by creating a `TopLevelClass`- and `Inner01`-instance on-the-fly. But you are right: this design is smelly.

Comment: @Turing85 And what would be the point of creating these instances on the fly, then discard them to create new ones? One _can_ do that, but it makes no sense :D.

Comment: @Tom as I wrote: the design is smelly.